# how to use Location (android.gms.location.*) into a Foreground service (Oreo, Pie, Android 10)

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-gps, android-10.0

According google documentation:

"Background Location Limits

In an effort to reduce power consumption, Android 8.0 (API level 26) limits how frequently background apps can retrieve the user's current location. Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour."

(https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

Well, this is interesting: Google maps works even with the screen off...
Either maps is not an app or the official documentation is badly written...
Does anyone know any way to get gps coordinates on android (api lever 26 or higher), when the app is in background? (screen off, or other app in use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incomplete..., they should add that to use background location you have to add permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```